# How to define a LLVM GlobalValue variable in C++ with llvm-10 library?

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

In LLVM-10 library, I didn't find any C++ API to define a LLVM GlobalValue, please help me.

Here's document of [LLVM-10 GlobalValue](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalVariable.html). But the constructor of GlobalValue is `protected`, not `public`.

Comment: What problem are you attending to solve? Are you trying to write an LLVM tool, or patch an existing one?

Comment: Most GlobalValues are GlobalVariables or Functions, both of which are simple to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GlobalValue` is a common base class for `Function` and `GlobalVariable`. It is not intended to be used directly, so you most probably want `GlobalVariable`, which does have public constructor: https://llvm.org/doxygen/GlobalVariable_8h_source.html#l00050